# copy command for json.gz from s3 to redshift

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, gzip

We have stored results of DDB to s3 output as json.gz files. We want to transfer those to redshift using the copy command. We don't want to do a direct DDB to Redshift because copying directly usually involves a scan operation. This causes read capacity to be utilized which we want to avoid since these tables are pretty large. I could not find much on how to use a copy command on a json.gz file. Please let me know if someone can find a way to do this.
I tried treating it like a json as suggested in one of the comments

 `copy itemtable  from 's3://bucket/path/file.json.gz'  iam_role '<role>' json 'auto ignorecase'`
 it did not work.
My file when unzipped is in this format: 
`{"Item":{"field":{"S":"value"},"field":{"N":"value"}}}'\n'{"Item":{"field":{"S":"value"},"field":{"N":"value"}}}'\n'`
Exact Error is 
`error is Load into table 'itemtable' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details`

Comment: Ignore the fact that it is a `.gz` file -- Redshift will handle that fine. Then follow [COPY from JSON format - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html). If you have a specific problem, please Edit your question to show a sample of your data, the `COPY` command you are using and the _exact_ error message.

Comment: I'd be great if you also add the specific error row from `stl_load_errors`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a few things worked for me.

```
from '<input s3 location>'
iam_role '<iam role>'
json '<jsonpath file location>' gzip ACCEPTINVCHARS ' ' TRUNCATECOLUMNS TRIMBLANKS
region '<aws region>'
```

here jsonpath.json file is in following format

```
{
  "jsonpaths": [
    "$['Item']['Field1']['S']",
    "$['Item']['Field2']['N']",
    .
    .
    .
  ]
}
```

And the table contains the same columns as fields specified in jsonpath.

As suggested in John Rotenstein's comment, the copy command takes care of gzip and we don't need to worry about it.